Why does `std::istream::seekg()` affect the behavior of `std::istreambuf_iterator`?
Why does std::istream::seekg() affect the behavior of std::istreambuf_iterator?
I carefully read the introduction about std::istreambuf_iterator on cppreference, but there is no direct answer for this matter.
Here is the code snippet:
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
 
int main()
{
    //with seekg to the end
    {
        std::cout << "#1 with seekg" << std::endl;
        std::istringstream in{"Hello, world"};
        in.seekg(std::istream::end);
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it{in}, end;
        std::string ss{it, end};
        std::cout << ss << std::endl;
    }

    //without seekg
    {
        std::cout << "#2 without seekg" << std::endl;
        std::istringstream in{"Hello, world"};
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it{in}, end;
        std::string ss{it, end};
        std::cout << ss << std::endl;
    }
    
    //seekg to end and then to begin
    {
        std::cout << "#3 seekg to end and then to begin" << std::endl;
        std::istringstream in{"Hello, world"};
        in.seekg(std::istream::end);
        std::streampos pos = in.tellg();
        std::cout << "len:" << static_cast<long long>(pos) << std::endl;
        in.seekg(std::istream::beg);
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it{in}, end;
        std::string ss{it, end};
        std::cout << ss << std::endl;
    }
}

Here is the output:
#1 with seekg
llo, world
#2 without seekg
Hello, world
#3 seekg to end and then to begin
len:2
Hello, world

I think the the ouput should be nothing or Hello, world for the fist case while the ouput is llo,world.

in.seekg(std::istream::end); == in.seekg(2, std::istream::beg);.  You probably wanted in.seekg(0, std::istream::end); to seek to the end.

@Eljay Why in.seekg(std::istream::end); == in.seekg(2, std::istream::beg);? Could you please shed some light on this matter?

@John end is an enum: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/seekdir.  It probably has a value of 2 on your system

You can see that in your output of len:2.  The input is longer than 2 characters.

There are two seekgs. You mixed them. If you want to go the the end of stream use seekg(0, end). seekg(end) uses end as an absolute position. end is implementation dependent, and in your case seems to be 2.

std::basic_istream::seekg() moves input position indicator to the given position.
According to the documentation the position is set by a numeric value.
The std::istreambuf_iterator, when it is created for the given istream, will point to the current input position.
So since seekg() modifies the input position value for the given istream, its call before creating iterator can have some affect on the iterator.
Now let's answer the question in the end of your post: why don't you observe empty string or full string in your code?
According to documentation seekg() has two overloads:

it can take as an argument single numeric value, which represents an  desired position relative to the beginning of the stream.
it can take as an argument numeric offset and some flag value to indicate the direction of that offset. This direction can be specified by std::ios_base::beg, std::ios_base::end, std::ios_base::curr values.

Now, in your code you pass only one argument to seekg() method. Thus you invoke the first overload.
But you pass to it some std::istream::end, which is, I assume, std::ios_base::end value, somehow imported into std::istream namespace. And you are lucky enough, so that its value is (or can be implicitly converted to) integer with value 2.
So basically in your code you write in.seekg(2), which results in moving the input position of the stream to the third character in your string (the character with index 2). As a result llo, world is printed.
In order to move the input position to the end of the buffer use
in.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
In order to move the position to the beginning of the buffer use
in.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg); or in.seekg(0);
By the way, your third example, where you moved input position "to the end and back" worked because std::istream::beg value is 0. So effectively there you did call in.seekg(0) before creating iterator and it read the string from its start.

std::istream is a class, which is defined to inherit from std::ios_base. std::istream::end naturally means std::ios_base::end by inheritance

Ah, yes you are right. I missed this point. Thank you for the clarification.

@BohdanLakatosh Thank you for the detailed explanation. You  said that when std::istreambuf_iterator is created for the given istream, will point to the current input position. However, I really can't  see any similar statement on the cppreference. Could you please give me any reference?

@John
1 - istreambuf_iterator reads characters from the input stream;
2 - istreambuf_iterator stores basic_streambuf pointer;
3 - basic_streambuf stores its state as 3 pointers: begin, end and next candidate for reading;
4 - basic_stream::seekg (by calling pubseekpos) repositions that "next pointer".

std::iostream::seekdir which is actually std::ios_base::seekdir is an implementation defined value of implementation defined type aliased as seekdir.
It is meant to be passed as second parameter of the std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::seekg overload that takes two parameters.
You have bad luck and seekdir can be passed also to the overload that accepts 1 parameter. I did not find a gcc warning level that catches this.
As mentioned in comments, from the output we can infer that the value of std::istream::end is 2. The position of the stream is moved 2 steps forward. And what you probably wanted instead is
in.seekg(0, std::istream::end);

To move the cursor to the end of the input stream.
